# Joda Time how to calculate how much time left?

Tags: java, jodatime, periodformatter

In this part of my code I want Joda Time to calculate and show how much time left until next birthday. So the year should change on birthday

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now();
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(x,m110,d110,h120,min120);
Period period = new Period(startDate, endDate, PeriodType.dayTime());
textView3.setText(formatter.print(period));
PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
                    .appendMonths().appendSuffix(".")
                    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" ")
                    .appendHours().appendSuffix(":")
                    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(":")
                    .appendSeconds()
                    .toFormatter();
```

x here is year, m110, d110, h120, min120 - month, day, hour and minute. What should I write instead of "x", so it could count how much time left every year and not once. And another question. When it's, for example, 3 hours, 4 minutes, what should I do in order to display "03:04:00" instead of "3:4:" (it also just doesn't show 0)

Answer (score 0):

The value of `x` is dependent of whether the birthday has already happend this year or not. You can check this using `DateTime.before` methods on the same day and month in the current year:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.now();
int year = startDate.getYear();
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(year,m110,d110,h120,min120);
if (endDate.isBefore(startDate)) // birthday happend already this year?
    endDate = endDate.plusYears(1); // then the next one is in the next year
```

As for your second question:
You can advice the [builder](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html) to create a formatter which always prints zeros using `printZeroAlways()`. To get the formatter to print at least two digits you can use the `minimumPrintedDigits` method:

```
   PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()            
        .minimumPrintedDigits(0)

        .appendMonths().appendSuffix(".")
        .printZeroAlways()
        .appendDays().appendSuffix(" ")

        .minimumPrintedDigits(2)

        .appendHours().appendSuffix(":")
        .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(":")
        .appendSeconds()
        .toFormatter();
```

Note that those methods only apply to the fields added **after** the invocation of the method. Also, the value may change along the builder's creation several times.